# Superclass __init__ overrides subclass constructor

Tags: python, python-3.x, init, shadowing, cantera

I am working with cantera, trying to create an expansion of `cantera.Solution` class by creating a subclass `Flow`. This is basically to expand description of gas phase with parameters of its movement.

`Solution` is constructed by using certain `**kwargs`. What I am trying to do, is to hold those `**kwargs` in a `Template` class object and use that object to define my `Flow` with that. I was trying to shadow `Solution.__init__` with `Flow.__init__` and pass parameters from `Template` using `super()`. However, `Solution.__init__` seems to override `Flow.__init__`.

```
class Flow(Solution):

  def __init__(self, template, velocity):

    super().__init__(species = template.species,
                     reactions = template.reactions, 
                     thermo = template.thermo, 
                     kinetics = 'GasKinetics')

    self.velocity = velocity
```

Now, let's assume i have a proper `Template` object under the name of `template`, which serves as a container for all those `**kwargs` required by `Solution.__init__`. I'm trying to create my `Flow` object:

```
flow = Flow(template, 230)
```

And i get:

```
AttributeError: 'Template' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

The very same error I would get if I attempted:

```
S = Solution(template, 230)
```

So basically all my subclass constructor parameters are passed to superclass' constructor. As the superclass constructor is not overridden, I can not use `Template` objects to define my `Solution` as a base for `Flow`. I read all around the web that this is not the default behaviour, as subclass constructor should override superclass constructor. How can this be helped?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution. Turns out, Cantera is based around cython. In fact, Solution class contains **init**, but it's not seen by Python as a function, but as a slot wrapper. Because of this, subclasses are unable to shadow **init** with their own constructor. I have handled this elegantly using unmentioned intestines of my code.