# Why does __init__ call the parent class's __init__ before the derived class's __init__?

Tags: python, cantera

I am using the `cantera` module in python, specifically trying to extend the class `cantera.Solution` using inheritance. The base class can be called like this:

```
gas = cantera.Solution("gri30.ct")
```

Where "gri30.cti" is the file name of the chemistry model to be used.

I am trying to make a new class, `SolutionExtended` which inherits from `cantera.Solution`. Here is the class definition:

```
class SolutionExtended(cantera.Solution):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Beginning of SolutionExtended.__init__")
        
        super().__init__("gri30.cti")
        
        print("End of SolutionExtended.__init__")
```

When instantiating the `SolutionExtended` object, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "E:\Projects\Coursework\Cantera\Code\test.py", line 15, in <module>
    gas = SolutionExtended()

  File "interfaces\cython\cantera\base.pyx", line 63, in cantera._cantera._SolutionBase.__cinit__

ValueError: Arguments are insufficient to define a phase
```

This is the same error that is thrown when you try to instantiate the parent class `cantera.Solution` without any input arguments (`gas = cantera.Solution()`).

Additionally, neither of the `print` statements actually print.

This leads me to thinking that `cantera.Solution.__init__` is being called *before* `SolutionExtended.__init__`, which fails because no input arguments are supplied. I am by no means a python expert, however, so this may be completely off.

**Can anyone tell me what is going on here? How would I make the `SolutionExtended` initialization work without requiring the chemistry model to be explicitly input?**

I'm pretty stumped by this, so I really appreciate any help. Thanks!

Here is my full code:

```
import cantera

gas = cantera.Solution('gri30.cti')
gas()

class SolutionExtended(cantera.Solution):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Beginning of SolutionExtended.__init__")
        
        super().__init__("gri30.cti")
        
        print("End of SolutionExtended.__init__")

        
gas = SolutionExtended()
gas()
```

Link to the `cantera` package website: https://cantera.org/

Comment: *”base.pyx, `_SolutionBase.__cinit__`”* — These are hints that this is not a plain class with a simple `__init__`, but at the very least a custom `__new__`, but more likely even deeper customizations in C. In fact there’s not even a guarantee that `__init__` will even be called; it’s just what default class constructors do.

Comment: @deceze That would seem to explain it. Is there a way to call the `Solution` class's constructor with an input within the `SolutionExtended` class's definition?

Comment: @Bryan M deceze is correct, this behavior is due to the presence of the `__cinit__` function. Probably the easiest thing to do is to avoid subclassing altogether and have a `ct.Solution` instance be an instance attribute on your extended class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Superclass \_\_init\_\_ overrides subclass constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64168584/superclass-init-overrides-subclass-constructor)